# How to output using Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to print 10,000 random numbers in ascending and descending order using Arrays.sort then output it. If I try it as this, it does not give the right output.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionFour 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int arr[] = new int[10000];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt( 100 ) + 1;
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            System.out.println(arr);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @dehasi please delete your comment, This is not how you print an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) does not have anything related with output, it only `sorts` an array

Let your loop fill the array, and after that `sort` and `print` it with [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))

```
int arr[] = new int[10000];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
    arr[i] = rand.nextInt( 100 ) + 1;
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

---

Reverse order sort :

1. You could use `Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.reverseOrder());`, but this requires an array of objects, it would requires a `Integer arr[] = new Integer[10000];` rather than `int`
2. Use a `List<Integer>` instead of en array, it would be easier to manipulate

   ```
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
   Random rand = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
       list.add(rand.nextInt(100) + 1);
   }
   list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
   System.out.println(list);             //[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 ...
   ```

Comment: Why does this print repeating numbers? For ex.: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3........

Comment: @tidematic because this is the content of you array, you input 10k element between 1 and 100, this is normal to have a lot of duplicate

Comment: If I were to do it in reverse order, how would I use Collections.reverseOrder()?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put `Arrays.sort(arr);` outside your for loop and create another loop for printing the array after it had been sorted.
your code should be as follows :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionFour 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int arr[] = new int[10000];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt( 100 ) + 1;

        }

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```